# Add css when @media print using less mixin and guard expressions

Tags: printing, less, media-queries

I want to avoid duplication in my code. Is it possible to write something like this in LESS?

```
.print when (@media print = true) {
    background: @heading-background-color !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
 }

  .header-month {
    .print
    background: @heading-background-color;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

Instead of:

```
@media print {
  .header-month {
    background: @heading-background-color !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
}

  .header-month {
    background: @heading-background-color;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

It doesn't look like an improvement here. But I'm working with multiple classes and need to do this for all of them.. So maybe an alternative if this is not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Less `@media` can be nested in a rule so you can define such `.print` mixin as:

```
.print() {
    @media print {
        background: @heading-background-color !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }
}

// usage:
.header-month {
    .print();
    background: @heading-background-color;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Also see ["Passing Rulesets to Mixins"](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) for a more complex stuff.